# After stopping production of opium, how does Afghanistan's government plan to offset the lost inflow of money going forward?

Tags: economy, trade, afghanistan, drugs, war-on-drugs

Thought some of the sources it cites are ten years old or more, Wikipedia's [Afghanistan; Economy; Agriculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan#Agriculture) says

> Agricultural production is the backbone of Afghanistan's economy and has traditionally dominated the economy, employing about 40% of the workforce as of 2018. The country is known for producing pomegranates, grapes, apricots, melons, and several other fresh and dry fruits. **It is also known as the world's largest producer of opium – as much as 16% or more of the nation's economy is derived from the cultivation and sale of opium.** It is also one of the world's top producers of cannabis.

ReliefWeb's March 22, 2022 [Afghanistan Opium Survey 2021 - Cultivation and Production](https://reliefweb.int/report/afghanistan/afghanistan-opium-survey-2021-cultivation-and-production) says:

> The production of opiates (opium, morphine, and heroin) is arguably Afghanistan’s largest illegal economic activity. The gross output of the Afghan illicit opiate economy was estimated to be $1.8-$2.7 billion in 2021. **The total value of opiates, including domestic consumption and exports, stood at between 9 to 14 per cent of Afghanistan’s GDP**, exceeding the value of its officially recorded licit exports of goods and services (estimated at 9 per cent of GDP in 2020).

ABC News's April 4, 2022 [Taliban clamp down on drugs, announce ban on poppy harvest](https://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/afghanistans-taliban-announce-ban-poppy-production-83843130) and CNN's April 3, 2022 [Taliban bans drug cultivation, including lucrative opium](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/04/03/asia/taliban-bans-drug-cultivation-opium-afghanistan-intl/index.html) are just examples of a story that's received widespread coverage, though it will take time for any drop in poppy production to be documented.

Wikipedia's [Heroin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroin) says:

> In 2015, Afghanistan produced about 66% of the world's opium.

which is a precursor for the production of both heroin and [pharmaceutical opiates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papaver_somniferum).

But I'm not asking about the Taliban-led government's announced decision nor its implementation. Instead I'm asking about how the government plans to offset this substantial loss of revenue.

**Question:** After stopping production of opium, how does Afghanistan's government plan to offset the plan to offset the lost inflow of money associated with their announced policy of stopping opium production going forward?

Comment: Does the government get tax revenue from opium production?

Comment: @divibisan I didn't specify *which kind* of revenue, and the figures I've cited are for GDP for example. Country's can have defined revenues as well as their governments, but perhaps there's a different term for that that you'd recommend? Presumably our shared goal is to optimize questions to facilitate the posting of interesting answers, not just find fault, right?

Comment: No need to get defensive. I’m just asking a clarifying question. Are you asking about explicit plans to replace lost tax revenue? Or if the Taliban will make afghan farmers while for their lost revenue? Or are you assuming the government cares about GDP and wants to maintain it? These are pretty different questions and I wanted to clarify what you were looking for, which is the main purpose for comments. Not every comment is “finding fault”

Comment: @divibisan My question only asks about how the government plans to *replace this inflow of money,* not about the details you've outlined. I'm assuming the government understands the importance of money in all its forms and for all its uses. That may include the government buying various things as well as the people getting enough food and basic medicines from outside sources; a problem that has been in the news since the takeover. If a major export is cut by a government, a replacement for the money it generates should perhaps be considered.

Comment: @divibisan I've replace "lost revenue" with "lost inflow of money" to help highlight why "Does the government get tax revenue from opium production?" isn't relevant to the scope of the question.

Comment: Well, it is relevant since it got you to clarify that you're *not* asking about budget and tax revenues. But the "plans to offset this substantial loss of revenue", if there are any, are going to be different for each type of loss of revenue, if they even care to. Replacing or dealing with lost revenue for the government is going to take a different plan than supporting farmers as they change crops, which will take a different plan than balancing foreign currency reserves needed for imports. I'm trying to clarify the focus – if you don't want to clarify, you're welcome to just not say anything

Comment: @divibisan I'll try to clarify further; any of those plans would be sufficient to be the basis of an answer. I don't see a good way to preclude any of them nor a  need to pre-constrain against any, and the very substance of an answer to "how does?" will likely address the "which one" automatically. The chances that there are several well developed, substantially different and publicized plans, one for each case, seem pretty remote to me.

Comment: Frankly I haven't seen any econ measures announced by the Taliban other than prohibiting women from work, which will of course work in the opposite direction. I guess they may be hoping the US might release some funds in return for this "war on drugs", but they're not saying it out loud. Russia, which was a major market for the Afghan opium, probably doesn't have much ability or inclination to help, being tied up with their war now. It's also worth noting they didn't even help Syria much to rebuild economically, where they are much more invested militarily.